# Difference between packing a struct vs union vs enum

Tags: c, enums, unions, packing, structure-packing

What is the difference between packing a struct vs. union vs. enum?

Regarding packed struct vs. packed union, there seems to be a minor difference in the assembly code generated on armv7l (but not on x86_64):

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct uint18_struct {
        unsigned int var:18;
} __attribute__((packed));

typedef struct uint18_struct uint18_struct_t;

union uint18_union {
        unsigned int var:18;
} __attribute__((packed));

typedef union uint18_union uint18_union_t;

int main (void)
{
        unsigned int bar = ~0U;
        volatile uint18_struct_t foo = *((uint18_struct_t *) &bar);
        printf ("max of uint18_t = %u\n", foo.var);
        volatile uint18_union_t baz = *((uint18_union_t *) &bar);
        printf ("max of bf_u18_t = %u\n", baz.var);
        return 0;
}
```

Generated assembly for foo and baz:

```
        volatile uint18_struct_t foo = *((uint18_struct_t *) &bar);
   10358:   f107 020c   add.w   r2, r7, #12
   1035c:   f107 0308   add.w   r3, r7, #8
   10360:   8811        ldrh    r1, [r2, #0]
   10362:   7892        ldrb    r2, [r2, #2]
   10364:   8019        strh    r1, [r3, #0]
   10366:   709a        strb    r2, [r3, #2]

        volatile uint18_union_t baz = *((uint18_union_t *) &bar);
   1037a:   f107 020c   add.w   r2, r7, #12
   1037e:   1d3b        adds    r3, r7, #4
   10380:   8811        ldrh    r1, [r2, #0]
   10382:   7892        ldrb    r2, [r2, #2]
   10384:   8019        strh    r1, [r3, #0]
   10386:   709a        strb    r2, [r3, #2]
```

Notice how the first two lines in the generated assembly (above `ldrh`) differs.

System details:

```
$ uname -a
Linux beaglebone 4.19.19-bone-rt-r21 #1stretch Wed Feb 6 11:01:34 UTC 2019 armv7l GNU/Linux
$ gcc --version
gcc (Debian 6.3.0-18+deb9u1) 6.3.0 20170516
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Cmdline I used:

```
$ gcc -g -O0 --save-temps main.c
```

Which one would you prefer to represent a uint18_t type - packed struct or packed union? Why?

---

EDIT: Imagine an embedded controller needing to process raw data of 9-bits (but CHAR_BIT is still 8) each (hence, the need for uint18_t) and does not provide stdint.h, limits.h.

Comment: If it followed the specifications for exact-width integer types (C23 7.20.1.1/2), a type `uint18_t` would be represented with exactly 18 bits (and no padding).  This is possible only in a C implementation that has 9-bit or 18-bit chars, because the size of every object other than a bitfield is a multiple of the size of a `char` (and `char` cannot be smaller than 8 bits).  Packing a struct or union does not work around that -- the size of the `struct` or `union` must be a multiple of the size of a `char`.

Comment: Also, `__attribute__((packed))` is a GNUism, and all other mechanisms for managing packing are likewise implementation specific.  There is no standard way to modulate structure layout or union size.

Answer (score 0):

> Which one would you prefer to represent a uint18_t type (?)

As

```
struct uint18_struct {
  uint_least32_t var:18;
}
```

*without* the `__attribute__((packed))`.  It is most portable that way.

On a 16-bit `int` system, hope that it accepts 32-bit int types in bit fields.

Otherwise consider the following and handle the sub-range needs myself.

```
struct uint18_struct {
  uint_least32_t var;
}
```

IMO, OP has not made a good case yet for needing the *packing*.  Perhaps once the larger issue is stated, we can work to solve the real problem.

Comment: "IMO, OP has not made a good case yet for needing the packing. Perhaps once the larger issue is stated, we can work to solve the real problem." Thanks for the suggestion. Just added. The bigger problem is that this system will not provide stdint.h. So the types will need to be defined by ourselves.

Comment: @ZeZNiQ  What version of C? `<stdint.h>` available since C99.  Could use `#if INT_MIN == -2147483648 typedef int my_int32_t #else ...`

Comment: Ya that's the problem. It is a bare metal system (think ROM validated on simulator/FPGA and no silicon yet) where I might potentially have to define these headers myself. At a minimum, I hope to expect atleast C89 compliance, in which case limits.h must be available (so that INT_MIN approach you proposed might work), but not sure. This begs another question - Could someone, for example, claim C99 compatibility without providing stdint.h and inttypes.h, or C89 compatibility without limits.h?

Comment: Put another way - could someone claim *partial* compliance to a specific version of C standard? Examples: C99-compliant without stdint.h and inttypes.h, C89-compliant without limits.h, etc.

Comment: @ZeZNiQ I'd say no.  Some things are optional like `complex` support, but not `stdint.h`.  IAC, what is `printf ("%d %ld\n", __STDC__, __STDC_VERSION__);`?

Comment: @ZeZNiQ BTW, Visual C lacked a `stdint.h` as for years they claimed only C89 compliance. Many community made substitutes existed.  I am certain either 1) you really do have a `stdint.h` or 2) a reasonable facsimile can be found or made.

Comment: \_\_STDC\_\_ prints 1 and \_\_STDC_VERSION\_\_ errors out with "error: \_\_STDC_VERSION\_\_ undeclared (first use in this function)".

Comment: Also, why would you prefer struct over union in this case?

Comment: Turns out, this particular system does not have stdint.h, but does allow passing -std=c99 to the gcc command so that printing \_\_STDC\_VERSION\_\_ yields 199901. Does that mean that this system by default (when no -std option is passed to gcc) is C89 std? Also, isn't this system a perfect example of being *partially* compliant to C99 since it allows for "-std=c99" to print the value of \_\_STDC\_VERSION\_\_, yet does not contain stdint.h?

Comment: @ZeZNiQ Looks to be C89 and not C99 compliant.  If with  "-std=c99" and has `__STDC_VERSION__` as `199901L` (What is it?), yet does not support variable length arrays, it is not compliant.  You can call it _partially compliant_, yet there is no specified definition of what _partially compliant_ means.

Comment: @ZeZNiQ I prefer `struct`.  There is only one member and looks like a mistake as a `union`.  Possible to have only one member in a `union`, yet that is a anti-pattern.